# Pandas - remove rows based on two conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this -

```
ColA            ColB                       ColC
Apple       2019-03-02 18:00:00        Saturday
Orange      2019-03-03 10:00:00        Sunday 
Mango       2019-03-04 09:00:00        Monday
```

I am trying to remove rows from my dateframe based on certain conditions.

1. Remove the row if the datetime is 9AM and above and 5PM and below.
2. Do not remove this, if it is weekend (Saturday and Sunday).

Expected output will not have Mango in the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems it is harder than what I thought

```
s1=df.ColB.dt.hour.between(9,17,inclusive=False)
df.loc[s1|df.ColC.isin(['Saturday','Sunday'])]
     ColA                ColB      ColC
0   Apple 2019-03-02 18:00:00  Saturday
1  Orange 2019-03-03 10:00:00    Sunday
```

---

Or using

```
s1=pd.Index(df.ColB).indexer_between_time('09:00:00','17:00:00',include_start =False ,include_end =False)
s1=df.index.isin(s1)
df.loc[s1|df.ColC.isin(['Saturday','Sunday'])]
```

Comment: Why not use dt.hour and dt.weekday? Think it becomes more readable. Could be 3 conditions.

Comment: I tried creating a new column like this - df['Time_BooleanResult'] = np.where((df['Time'].between_time("8:59:59","5:00:01")),True,False) but it says index must be a date time index. Any Idea why ? Yes, Time column is an extract of time from date time column.

Comment: @Sid29 between_time is for index , so if you want to using this method , you need , index as datetime , also I do not think this is right way of doing this

Comment: @AntonvBR I know why I did that rather that using hour , since my method can be work for hh:mm:ss, for eaxmple the cut point is '09:30:30' dt.hour dose not work

Answer (score 1):

To give another alternative you could write it like this:

```
cond1 = df.ColB.dt.hour >= 9   # After 09:00
cond2 = df.ColB.dt.hour <= 15  # Before 16:00
cond3 = df.ColB.dt.weekday < 5 # Mon-Fri

df = df[~(cond1&cond2&cond3)]
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ColA': ['Apple','Orange','Mango'],
    'ColB': pd.to_datetime([
        '2019-03-02 18:00:00', 
        '2019-03-03 10:00:00', 
        '2019-03-04 09:00:00'
     ]),
    'ColC': ['Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday']
})

cond1 = df.ColB.dt.hour >= 9   # After 09:00
cond2 = df.ColB.dt.hour <= 15  # Before 16:00
cond3 = df.ColB.dt.weekday < 5 # Mon-Fri

df = df[~(cond1&cond2&cond3)] # conditions mark the rows to drop, hence ~

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
     ColA                ColB      ColC
0   Apple 2019-03-02 18:00:00  Saturday
1  Orange 2019-03-03 10:00:00    Sunday
```